# How to monitor execution time per endpoint when using Express with Google Cloud Functions?

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-functions

I have a Cloud Function, actually, a Firebase Function, running on Node.js runtime that serves an API based on Express Framework. Looking at the function logs I have outputs like this (real data omitted):

```
{
  "insertId": "000000-00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
  "labels": {
    "execution_id": "000000000000"
  },
  "logName": "projects/project-00000/logs/cloudfunctions.googleapis.com%2Fcloud-functions",
  "receiveTimestamp": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z",
  "resource": {
    "labels": {
      "function_name": "api",
      "project_id": "project-00000",
      "region": "us-central1"
    },
    "type": "cloud_function"
  },
  "severity": "DEBUG",
  "textPayload": "Function execution took 5000 ms, finished with status code: 200",
  "timestamp": "2000-01-01T00:00:00.000000000Z",
  "trace": "projects/project-00000/traces/00000000000000000000000000000000"
}
```

The relevant data I wanted to extract is the execution time and response code, in the `textPayload` attribute. However, I wanted to create a metric that breaks the data for each API endpoint to identify which endpoints are slow. This is an HTTP function but I don't have any request detail in the logs.

I probably can achieve what I want coding the logs into the function. However, I was wondering if I can extract the info directly from Google Cloud without touching the code function.

There is a way to create a log-based metric to show execution times split in endpoints?

References:

- https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/monitored-metrics
- https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/monitoring/metrics

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe this will be possible without writing code.  If you want to collect information about some running code, typically folks turn to [Stackdriver](https://cloud.google.com/products/operations), and use its APIs to collection specific information for analysis.